# Why is function in kernel32.dll jumping into a api-ms-win-core stub

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10

I was trying to look into the implementation of `GetVersion` function in **kernel32.dll**.

I was surprised to see that the `GetVersion` thunk is issuing a jump to `API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL::GetVersion`, and in turn `API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL::GetVersion` is pointing(forwarder) back to `KERNEL32.DLL::GetVersion`



Any idea why is it so? So where is the real implementation of `GetVersion`?

##### Kernel32.dll

[image: kernel32.dll]

##### API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-1-0.DLL

[image]

Comment: to make universal crt possible most implementation were shifted to other dlls and a version agnostic stub which knows where to redirect the backward compatible and present apis were introduced  which is contained in a resource only dll file named APISETSCHEMEA.dll  you may check here for some internals of that [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/reverse-function-in-rdata-field/31133#31133)

Comment: What @blabb said! Plus, you may want to read [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/windows_7_kernel_architecture_changes.html) and [this](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm) and [this](https://lucasg.github.io/2017/10/15/Api-set-resolution/) as well as the code in [this](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and [this](https://github.com/zodiacon/ApiSetView). Enjoy. Oh and [my answer on the Q&A blabb linked](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/31098/245) also offers details about _this_ topic.

Answer (score 1):

`GetVersion()` was deprecated in 8.1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1

So I would guess that they've left the function stub there to catch and redirect calls in code that hasn't been updated.

Comment: I did tried to create a dummy program to test out `GetVersion` and it's working fine.

Comment: Besides that there are also some function that is not deprecated that has the same footprint.

Comment: Deprecated means you shouldn't use it, not you can't. However, `GetVersion()` does anyway lie all the time unless your application happens to run with a manifest that proclaims full compatibility with the Windows release on which it runs. For the truth use [`RtlGetVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/rtlgetversion) or consult `KUSER_SHARED_DATA`. Either way, what you encountered is more about API sets than about whether `GetVersion` is deprecated.

Comment: @MegaTonnage: I think in this question it's more about the API Sets rather than about why it's deprecated or so.